# Microsoft Graph API: Filter Calendar Events by Location

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata, office365api

I'm trying to filter all events by a location displayName.  Since location is a complex property and displayName is nested, I need help on how to do this.  I've tried the following but neither work.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$expand=location($filter=displayName eq 'East Conference Room')

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=location/displayName/'East](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=location/displayName/%27East) Conference Room'

Comment: How about `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=location/displayName eq 'East Conference Room'`?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by using the $filter parameter in the api.

[Use query parameters to customize responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter)

I worked out your example by adapting the emails example in the documentation, which also filters by a nested parameter and compares to a string.

> Get all emails from a specific address received by the signed-in user.    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq 'someuser@example.com'

Therefore, for your use case, i.e. to only get calendar events with a location displayName equal to "East Conference Room", it would be:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=location/displayName eq 'East Conference Room'
```